# Adding a class to a ListItem of an asp:DropDownList from jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to add a class from jQuery to the first item of an asp ddl (in case the user didn't select another item before submitting).

i have tried:

```
$("#my_ddl").options[0].addClass("myErrorClass");
```

didn't work, any suggestions please?
thx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a couple of issues here. Firstly jQuery objects don't have an `options` collection. Secondly, if they did, accessing it by index (ie. using `[0]`) would return an Element object not a jQuery object, and the former does not have an `addClass()` method.

To fix this you can use various jQuery methods entirely to add the class, any of these will work:

```
$('#my_ddl option:first').addClass('myErrorClass');
$('#my_ddl option').first().addClass('myErrorClass');
$('#my_ddl').find('option').first().addClass('myErrorClass');
$('#my_ddl').children('option:first').addClass('myErrorClass');
$('#my_ddl').children('option').first().addClass('myErrorClass');
```

Alternatively you can use native JS methods:

```
document.querySelector('#my_ddl option')[0].classList.addClass('myErrorClass');
```

***However***, the major caveat to all this that adding classes to `option` elements for the purposes of styling is not reliable in all browsers. Make sure you test the output is what you expect it to be in all cases.

Comment: Hello, that did work, however i only see the change when i open the list on the first item (not on the currently selected item).
i tried $('#my_ddl option:selected').addClass('myErrorClass'), it gives the same effect, any idea?

Comment: This is what I referred to in the answer about inconsistencies with adding styling to individual `option` elements. Honestly, I would suggest you avoid it entirely and do whatever you need another way